# Docusign Signer Attachment

Tags: docusignapi

Using the Docusign SOAP API, I'm stuck.

I want the last recipient of the envelope to attach a document - nothing more. No signature needed for this. So, questions:

1. I presume I set this recipient as SignerAttachment ?
2. Do I also need to create a Tab for this recipient, or is #1 above sufficient?
3. Does the recipient need to know/understand anything about Base64 encoding or is it a simple file upload?

Kinda amazed that several hours of looking just don't answer these basic questions - DS's documentation offers almost nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The recipient will need a type of "Signer" as any recipient with tags will always be a signer. You will also need to add a tab called SignerAttachment for this recipient.

You can find basic info on signer attachments [here](https://www.docusign.com.au/support/classic/documentation/cdse-user-guide/signing/signer-attachments).

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure it out, and now I have a bunch of envelopes out there with the wrong configuration. The pertinent parts that I've added are shown below. But the recipient doesn't see any tab for attaching a document. Any suggestions on what I've done wrong here?

```
           <Recipient>
                <ID>5</ID>
                <RoutingOrder>5</RoutingOrder>                       
                <UserName>Any Signer</UserName>
                <SignerName>Any Signer</SignerName>
                <Email>******@******.com</Email>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
            </Recipient>

            <Tab>
                <DocumentID>94401</DocumentID>
                <RecipientID>5</RecipientID>
                <Type>SignerAttachment</Type>
                <AnchorTabItem>
                    <AnchorTabString>/sAt/</AnchorTabString>
                    <XOffset>0</XOffset>
                    <YOffset>0</YOffset>
                    <Unit>Inches</Unit>
                    <IgnoreIfNotPresent>true</IgnoreIfNotPresent>
                </AnchorTabItem>
            </Tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this SOAP Sample will get you started:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:CreateAndSendEnvelope>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns:Envelope>        
            <ns:AccountId>{{ACCOUNT_ID}}</ns:AccountId>
            <!--Optional:-->
          <ns:Documents>
                <ns:Document>
                     <ns:ID>100</ns:ID>
                     <ns:Name>Sample</ns:Name>
                     <ns:PDFBytes>{{BASE64_BYTES}}</ns:PDFBytes>            
                     <ns:FileExtension>TXT</ns:FileExtension>
                </ns:Document>
          </ns:Documents>
            <ns:Recipients>
                  <ns:Recipient>
                    <ns:ID>1</ns:ID>
                    <ns:UserName>{{RECIPIENT_NAME}}</ns:UserName>
                    <ns:Email>{{RECIPIENT_EMAIL}}</ns:Email>
                    <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
                    <ns:AccessCode></ns:AccessCode>
                    <ns:RoutingOrder>1</ns:RoutingOrder>                    
                  </ns:Recipient>
           </ns:Recipients>
           <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:Tabs>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <ns:Tab>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <ns:DocumentID>100</ns:DocumentID>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <ns:RecipientID>1</ns:RecipientID>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <ns:XPosition>10</ns:XPosition>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <ns:YPosition>10</ns:YPosition>
                  <ns:Type>SignerAttachment</ns:Type>
               </ns:Tab>
            </ns:Tabs>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:Subject>Signer Attachment</ns:Subject>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ns:EmailBlurb>Create an Envelope From CreateAndSendEnvelope - Signer Attachment </ns:EmailBlurb>
            <ns:SigningLocation>Online</ns:SigningLocation>
            <ns:Notification>
               <!--Optional:-->
               <ns:UseAccountDefaults>1</ns:UseAccountDefaults>
            </ns:Notification>            
         </ns:Envelope>
      </ns:CreateAndSendEnvelope>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see what I'm to learn from your example that suggests what to change in my code? 

And, while this is probably beside the point, I don't know that I've ever seen nomenclature like this with the ns: prefix. I just don't see what you're telling me is wrong with what I'm using.

Comment: I see that your SignerAttachment tag is setup to use anchor text. I failed to include that in my code sample. I see that you currently have the node IgnoreIfNotPresent set to true. This means that if the anchor text /sAt/ is not included in the underlying document this tag will not be applied. Changing this value to false will cause the request to fail if the text does not exist. I currently suspect the (/sAt/) text may not exist in the PDF bytes being passed.

Comment: For those following along at home, I've privately sent Deana the PDFBytes, where she confirms she sees the anchor text. I've also set IgnoreIfNotPresent to False for today's envelopes, which are all being sent just fine - we have no errors. Except, of course, the fact that the Attachment tag still isn't showing up.

Comment: Steve, Still waiting for the API logs of your current request. Please respond to the support case with those logs. Thanks.